# Razor Pages This Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I've done a clean install of Visual Studio 2019 on my computer and have created a Razor Page

I have done 0 changes to the code, expecting to go to the default page when i start debugging without changing.

However i am getting a 
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.

Error.

I got the popup Would you like to Trust the IIS Express SSL Certificate, however i accidentally clicked no with 'don't ask me again' ticked. Could this be the issue?

If so can i get this popup back?

Comment: Can you try to use http:// instead of https://?

Comment: Thanks @Alex-TinLe, i went into the project properties and unticked enable SSL based off your suggestion, which has worked! :) Any ideas how i can sort out the trust IIS express SSL Certificate?

Comment: You can start from this post (https://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: I have followed this guide and have installed the certificate as it said https://i.gyazo.com/9d6c8a16ff7d66c6f5b6905ddb4dc5b9.png but i still cannot tick 'enable ssl' in the project properties

Comment: you can just disable ssl all together... I usually enable it only on production but not on development.